# Xamarin RotateTo is not rotating from center ( images or views ) on UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

- **Xamarin.Forms Version:** 4.2.0.709249 ( latest ).
- **UWP Target:** 16299

I am trying to rotate images and views, and I've tried most of I've been figuring to fix the issue without luck.

On Android images and views are rotating properly from the center, but on UWP there's a displacement and it's just at center each 4 rotations. Then things like spinners are rendering really ugly.

**C#**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CheckSpinner
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            while (true)
            {
                await Spinner.RotateTo(360, 36000, Easing.Linear);
                await Spinner.RotateTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="CheckSpinner.MainPage">

    <StackLayout
        Padding="16">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label 
           Text="Check that the square is not spinning from the center properly!" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           />

        <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="absoluteLayout">
                <BoxView
                    x:Name="Spinner"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .5"
                    HeightRequest="300"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    Color="Aqua" />
                <BoxView
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .5"
                    HeightRequest="8"
                    WidthRequest="8"
                    Color="Red" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[Sample project showing issue](https://displaynote-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/miguel_delamor/Ea4YXwSPmw9Cg01YtA4YyZ8BhQdOp-0nQly1KEBWpBoVpA?e=mVNkhA)
[Gif showing the bad rotation on UWP](https://displaynote-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/p/miguel_delamor/EZnCqiIuhQJIt1d_LyoqBIoBG0m61iZW5j-A954zqbd-nw?e=cg0XFQ)

P.D.:

- I've tried with many layout combinations and same happens.
- On Android it's rotating properly.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: I've tried with 4.2, 4.1 and 4.0. do you know a version in which this works?

Comment: @forlayo,I test your sample, but I think it is the same.

Comment: @CherryBu If you check with attention the left side of both squares, you'll see that while in same rotation they don't match ( a little blue line appears ); and each 4-5 spins it match. 

If instead of using a boxview, you set a round image for an spinner. You'll see it's bouncing like a deflated wheel..